# Connecting to a Yum Repo on RHEL5

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5, repository

When I run a yum update I get the following error

```
yum update
Gathering header information file(s) from server(s)
Server: Red Hat Enterprise 5Server - RPMforge.net - dag
retrygrab() failed for:
  http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/headers/header.info
  Executing failover method
failover: out of servers to try
Error getting file http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/headers/header.info
[Errno 4] IOError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

This is my /etc/yum.conf file:

```
[main]
cachedir=/var/cache/yum
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
pkgpolicy=newest
distroverpkg=redhat-release
tolerant=1
exactarch=1

[rpmforge]
name = Red Hat Enterprise $releasever - RPMforge.net - dag
baseurl = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/$basearch/rpmforge
mirrorlist = http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/mirrors-rpmforge
enabled = 1
protect = 0
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-rpmforge-dag
gpgcheck = 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[rpmforge]` stanza from your config file and then [enable it properly](https://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using).

Answer (score 0):

Change your baseurl to include /RPMS/.